# How to parse custom X509v3 extension in golang?

Tags: go, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I have a client.crt.pem.

I want to get the custom extension key-value.

(e.g.

`2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.1` and `G1`,

or

`2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.1` and `0C024731`

).

**How to parse them in golang?**

Here is the certificate info.

Use `openssl x509 -in client.crt.pem -noout -text` to show it.

```
...
...
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type:
                SSL Client, S/MIME
            Netscape Comment:
                OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection
            2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.1:
                ..G1
            2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.2:
                ..R1
            2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.3:
                ..3
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, DNS:localhost
...
...
```

Or use `openssl asn1parse -i -in client.crt.pem`

```
...
...
  998:d=4  hl=2 l=  18 cons:     SEQUENCE
 1000:d=5  hl=2 l=  10 prim:      OBJECT            :2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.1
 1012:d=5  hl=2 l=   4 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0C024731
 1018:d=4  hl=2 l=  18 cons:     SEQUENCE
 1020:d=5  hl=2 l=  10 prim:      OBJECT            :2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.2
 1032:d=5  hl=2 l=   4 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0C025231
 1038:d=4  hl=2 l=  17 cons:     SEQUENCE
 1040:d=5  hl=2 l=  10 prim:      OBJECT            :2.9.1.6.2.6.1.9.9.4.3
 1052:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0C0133
...
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? Were you able to parse x509 in Go at all?

Comment: Hi, @rustyx, I have added my answer. I'm not sure whether it doesn't have any potential bug. Anyway, it works fine now.

Comment: You can find the implementation of [func X509KeyPair](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/tls.go) here. It decodes the certPEMBlock in a loop. I don't know why. Could you tell me? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,

FYI.

```golang
func getCustomExtensions(serverCertFile string, customOIDPrefix string) ([]pkix.Extension, bool) {
    certBytes, err := os.ReadFile(serverCertFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false
    }
    block, _ := pem.Decode(certBytes)
    if block.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
        certificate, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, false
        }
        var extensions []pkix.Extension
        for _, ext := range certificate.Extensions {
            // filter the custom extensions by customOID
            if strings.Contains(ext.Id.String(), customOIDPrefix) {
                extensions = append(extensions, ext)
            }
        }
        return extensions, true
    }

    return nil, false
}
```